# Where can I find the implementation of stdio.h in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, header-files, stdio

I could find **stdio.h** header file easily through search in Windows Explorer, but couldn't find its implementation file like stdio.lib(?). Where can I find it?

Additionally, I can't find Windows.h through search in Windows Explorer, although I can compile source code with Windows.h included.

Is there anybody to explain about this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The sources for the CRT (C Runtime) are included in the Visual Studio install directory, under **VC\crt\src**.  There are many files; you'll need to find the one that defines the functionality in which you are interested.

The Windows headers (including Windows.h) are included in the Windows SDK, in which there is an **Include** directory which contains the headers.  Where exactly these files are located on your computer depends entirely on where you installed the Windows SDK.

Comment: But, implementation file for stdio.h didn't seem to be found there... I can compile source code that contains printf() with stdio.h included. Linker doesn't report any error at all. Somewhere in my hdd implementation code for stdio.h must be exist. Where can I find it? I know this can be somewhat funny or easy question. But I don't know the answer and am just curious about it. :-$

Comment: The source code is in **printf.c** under the directory noted in the answer.  The library is in whichever one of the [C Runtime Libraries](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/abx4dbyh.aspx) against which you are linking.  Those libraries are in the **VC\lib** folder in the Visual Studio installation directory.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I found printf.c file. But, still I don't know why my helloworld project build so well although I never imported printf.c in my project and never compiled it. That only means linker found implementation of printf() in some place out of my project. In my project property page > Config. property > Linker > Input > Additional dependencies there are some .lib files such as kernel32.lib, user32.lib, gdi32.lib, ... Is implementation code of printf() funciton in one of these .lib files?

Comment: It's in each of the C Runtime Libraries, one of which is linked into your program, depending on which flag is passed to the compiler.  See the page to which I linked in my previous comment.

Answer (score 0):

Based on accepted answer. For VC++6, it typically locates on:

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\VC98\Lib\MSVCRT.LIB`

Verify it by opening that file with Notepad, and search '_printf'.

Answer (score 0):

Since 2015, you have to install "Universal CRT SDK". Then you can find the code from `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10` directory.

You can see here from more details.
https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/introducing-the-universal-crt/